# How to transform nested parameters in Rails API for PATCH requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api-design

I'm having problems trying to implement a PATCH endpoint for a Rails API which deals with complex request objects that are structurally different from the `ActiveRecord` model.

As an example let's say I have the following request object:

```
{
    "details": {
        "color": {
            "id": 1
        }
    },
    "name": "Hello, world!"
    ...
}
```

However, on my model I expect a flat `color_id` attribute:

```
class CreateModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :model do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.integer :color_id, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Therefore I need to transform the request params. For this I've found one approach which works pretty well in case of PUT requests, but not at all for PATCH:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new({
    color_id: params.dig(:details, :color, :id),
    name: params.dig(:name)
})
```

If I issue a PUT request this solution works great since PUT expects the whole object as payload, PATCH on the other hand would cause issues when passing only a subset of the properties since everything else will be set to `nil` due to how `dig` works.

Assuming I have no control over the request format, how can I transform the request params in the backend so that omitted keys will not result in `nil` values? Of course I could imperatively handle each property line by line, checking whether the key is present in the original params and then setting it in the new one, but is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a generic solution using mapping logic with a lookup table. For the example above:

```
{
    "details": {
        "color": {
            "id": 1
        }
    },
    "name": "Hello, world!"
    ...
}
```

I would have the following mapping variable:

```
MAPPING = {
    [:details, :color, :id] => [:color_id]
}
```

Then I'm able to transform the params using this recursive algorithm:

```
def handle(params, keys)
    output = Hash.new
    params.each do |k,v| 
        sym_keys = (keys + [k]).map &:to_sym
        target_keys = MAPPING[sym_keys]
        if v.is_a? ActionController::Parameters
            keys << k
            output = output.deep_merge! transform(v, keys)
        else
            if target_keys.nil?
                value = sym_keys.reverse().reduce(v) { |v, k| Hash[k, v] }
            else
                value = target_keys.reverse().reduce(v) { |v, k| Hash[k, v] }
            end
            output = output.deep_merge! value
        end
    end
    output
end

def transform(params)
    output = handle(params, [])
end
```